# How can we handle threshold limit of SharePoint?

Tags: c#, sharepoint

SharePoint is configured with a default threshold limit of 5000 items in a list or library. This means that if the items in a list or library exceed that number, any views, grouping and queries will fail, So there is any work-around/solution to handle this issue of SharePoint by API? and Why SharePoint set such a rule?

Comment: https://sharepointmaven.com/how-to-overcome-sharepoint-5000-item-limit-threshold/

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint list view threshold limitation is used to make sure SharePoint high Performance and stable.

You could use Indexed Column in CAML Query or Rest API to handle this limitation:

[SharePoint List View Threshold: Your FAQs Answered](https://www.maargasystems.com/sharepoint-list-view-threshold-faqs-answered/)

Answer (score 0):

Normally we dont need huge amount of data on a single page. It will be use less for a user as he cant see all.

But we can use as workaround to fetch data in chunks and append array of data in loop. Check the below blog. i hope it may help you.

https://abdulazizfarooqi.wordpress.com/2016/03/20/sharepoint-defeat-5000-threshold/

Another way is to use index column as mentioned already, use more filters in your query to get the less amount of data which may be useful for end user rather just bring all at once.

In SPFX we can use react component paging to fetch data as per page using rest api.